# Big query - Concatenate strings horizontally

Tags: google-bigquery, string-concatenation

I have a data with a column for the first name and a column for the last name.
I try to combine the them into one column via code:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(full_name,' ') 
from (Select first_name as check from [DATA]), 
     (select last_name  as check from [DATA])
```

But it returns a one row string with

> Anna Alex Emma Sean .... Miller Smith White ...

but what I wanted was actually a column like

```
Anna Miller
Alex Smith
Emma White
...
```

Can you please tell me what I should do differently?
Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use [CONCAT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#stringfunctions) and the trim functions

```
SELECT CONCAT(rtrim(ltrim(first_name)),' ',rtrim(ltrim(last_name))) AS full_name
FROM
  (SELECT 'Anna' AS first_name,
          ' Miller ' AS last_name),
```

Comment: Thank you, it works in most of the cases but if the value for first_name or last_name is null, it returns null. I tried with 
     string(first_name) 
but it stays null. I'd expect it to return e.g. Sean null or Sean NoName.

Comment: You need to add `IFNULL(first_name,'null')`,  `IFNULL(first_name,'NoName')`

Comment: Also SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(first_name))+' '+RTRIM(LTRIM(last_name)) would work (+ instead of CONCAT)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the double pipe `||` concatenation operator for concatenation of strings ([see here for more info](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators)):

```
select 
    trim(first_name) || ' ' || trim(last_name)
from
    ...
```